# Remember user timezone selection, and apply timezone changes to datetime field on all pages

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

In my database I have a dateandtime field in one of the tables, which correctly displays the date and time from the database for the row I want. As I will possibly get users from many different countries I will need to allow a user to select their timezone so that the time in the time and date in the dateandtime field will be changed to their timezone across all pages of my site.

I am able to successfully allow the user to type in a input field the time zone such as "+3:00" and enter a date such as "24/07/2017" into another input field, and when the user clicks the Search button the timezone conversion will be successful. This is not ideal though as it means everytime the user goes to another page on the site and goes back to the search by date page they have to input the timezone e.g. "+3:00" again.

I was thinking that a session could be used to achieve what I need but when I tried using a session to remember the timezone value when I went back to the page the time would no longer be in the timezone I had previously inputted.

To summarise, what I am trying to achieve is that I would like the user to be able to select their timezone and for any dates and times displayed on the webpages from the database will be changed to the users selected timezone, and if the user was to go off the page then their timezone will be remembered if they were to go back to the previous page.

An example site that shows what I am trying to achieve successfully is below

[A site which has the functionality with timezones I am attempting to achieve](http://liveonsat.com/los_soc_int_UEFA_CL.php)

As you can see on that site if I select timezone, it successfully changes the timezone, and if I was to select another section of the site it would remember the users timezone and update the date and time to reflect the timezone changes. It seems after inspection that that site uses a cookie to remember the timezone value, would I be able to use cookies to achieve this type of functionality on my site?

Below is the code I have that successfully changes the timezone when the user inputs a timezone value e.g. "+3:00" and date into the corresponding input fields but will not remember timezone option.

```
<?php
include './config.php';
include './header.php';





$timezone = trim($_GET["timezone"]);
$keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
if ($keyword <> "" && $timezone <> "" ) {
$sql = "SELECT f.hometeam, f.awayteam, f.sport, f.competition,
DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(f.dateandtime, '+00:00','$timezone'), '%M %e, %Y %r') AS dateandtime,
Group_concat(s.name SEPARATOR ',') name,
Group_concat(x.channelid_fc SEPARATOR ',') channelid_fc
FROM footballfixtures f
LEFT JOIN fixturechannels x
ON x.matchid_fc=f.matchid
LEFT JOIN satellite s
ON x.channelid_fc=s.channelid
WHERE DATE(dateandtime) = STR_TO_DATE('$keyword', '%d/%m/%Y')
GROUP BY f.hometeam, f.awayteam, f.sport, f.competition, f.dateandtime
ORDER BY f.dateandtime ";

$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");
$stmt->bindValue(":timezone", $timezone." %");


$stmt->execute();

} else {


$sql = "SELECT 1 from dual";

$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
}

$stmt->execute();





?>
<html>

<head>






</head>

<body>

<div class="container mainbody">
<div class="mainpagetitle">
<h11>Sports Schedule</h11> <br> <br>
<p>We aim to provide you with sports schedule in an easy to view  format</p> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<form class="form-inline">
</div>


<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
      <img src="css/calendar.png" class="img-responsive" />

               <div id=class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <h2>Search by Date</h2> <br>
<p> Please Enter Date </p>

</div>  
</div>
</div>


<div class="searchform">
    <form action="bydate.php" method="get" >
        <label class="col-xs-12" for="timezone";>
          <select name="timezone" id="timezone">
<option value="+1:00">+1:00</option>
<option value="+2:00">+2:00</option>
<option value="+3:00">+3:00</option>
<option value="+4:00">+4:00</option>
</select>

        </label>






  <div class="searchform">
    <form action="bydate.php" method="get" >
        <label class="col-xs-12" for="keyword";>
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["keyword"]); ?>" placeholder="Enter Team Name" id="" class="form-control" name="keyword">

        </label>



      <button class="btn btn-info">search</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>




  <div class="clearfix"></div>


 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="tables">
 <div class="col-xs-12">


 <table class="table table-hover footable">
 <thead>
 <tr>
            <th>Home Team</th>
              <th> vs </th>
            <th>Away Team</th>
            <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Sport</th>
            <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Competition</th>
            <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Date and Time</th>
            <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Channels</th>  
            </tr>
          </thead>

  <?php         

  if($stmt->rowCount() >0) {   

       while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {


     $hometeam = $row['hometeam'];
     $versus= $row['versus'];
         $awayteam= $row['awayteam'];
         $sport= $row['sport'];
         $competition = $row['competition'];
         $dateandtime=$row['dateandtime'];
         $name=explode(',', $row['name']);
         $channelid=explode(',', $row['channelid_fc']);

    ?>
    <tbody>

  <tr>
  <td> <?php echo $row[hometeam] ; ?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $row[versus] ; ?> </td>
 <td> <?php echo $row[awayteam] ; ?> </td>
 <td> <?php echo $row[sport] ; ?> </td>
 <td> <?php echo $row[competition] ; ?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $row[dateandtime] ; ?> </td>

<td>
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($channelid) && $i < count($name); ++$i) {
$achannelid = $channelid[$i];
$aname = $name[$i];


        echo "<a href='http://sportschedule.xyz/view_channels.php?channelid=" .$achannelid."'> ".$aname." </br> </a> ";

        }

        ?>

  </tbody>       
</td>
 </tr>
<?php  } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<p>No matches found for the team you searched. Please try again</p>
 <?php } ?>
</table>   

   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <script>

   $('.footable').footable({ addRowToggle: false });


      $('.footable').footable({
  calculateWidthOverride: function() {
    return { width: $(window).width() };
  }
}); 

    $(document).ready(function(){ if ($.trim($(".footable tbody").text()).length == 0) { $('.footable').hide(); } });  

</script>


      </body>
      </html>
```

Many Thanks to anyone who reads, and/or suggests how I could achieve a solution or steers me in the right direction for assistance

Comment: I think you can do this automatically using javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript You can get the browser timezone which is basically the timezone of the user computer and you can use that. Another useful library for this : http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: I'm guessing you are calling session_start() on each page load. Maybe put that in your config or header if you include those in every page. That should make your session info "sticky". Just a thought!

Comment: I think session_start as suggested by TimBrownlaw is what I need, the issue I am having is that I have dropdowns on each of my pages with the timezone that is send via GET method when the user performs a search, Would I be best to have one page where the user can select their time zone, which will pass that value into the session, and start the session on each of the other pages without a dropdown for the timezone, and the timezone can be taken from the session and update the datetime field values in my table?

Comment: TimBrownlaw, would it be possible to write an answer showing how I could achieve your method? Many Thanks

Comment: I tried to use session_start(); 
 $_SESSION['timezone']='$timezone'; in header.php page. I tried adding session_start();
echo $_SESSION['timezone']; to the page that needs to have the timezone value passed in and the only output I get is $timezone in the header output.    The way I  set it up with the GET variable outputs a URL as such http://sportschedule.xyz/bydate.php?timezone=%2B3%3A00&keyword=24%2F08%2F2017 This displays the new timezone correctly in the table on my site, but I how do I get the $_SESSION to be passed into URL string automatically when user searches by date for example.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the most correct approach on this issue is the following:
- save the timezone on each user in database or in cookie (if you dont have authenticated users)
- create a global variable in php and javascript which you'll use all over your website called user_date
- at the start of the page make that user_date equal to the DateTime + timezone
You have to have a variable and everytime you make a date calculation use that timezone.

---

Also i will leave here my other answer, related to how you can achieve this directly in your browser, without php and database relation.

I think you can do this automatically using javascript. stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/… You can get the browser timezone which is basically the timezone of the user computer and you can use that. Another useful library for this : momentjs.com/timezone